# How to remove a specific element in array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

If I have array, for example:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

I need something like

```
a.remove("a");
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Settle Down. I'm coming up with a duplicate for you since you clearly didn't search for yourself.

Comment: arr.splice(arr.indexOf(elm),1) will remove an element 'elm' from array 'arr'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var newArray = [];
var a=["a","b","c"];
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    if(a[i]!=="a") 
        newArray.push(a[i]);
```

As of newer versions of JavaScript:

```
var a = ["a","b","c"];
var newArray = a.filter(e => e !== "a");
```

Comment: You know there is `.splice` right?

Comment: Yes, I know. But I'm considering that the array can have more than one "a"

Comment: I didn't think of that. Good point. +1

Comment: The array has only unique values !

Answer (score 7):

```
remove = function(ary, elem) {
    var i = ary.indexOf(elem);
    if (i >= 0) ary.splice(i, 1);
    return ary;
}
```

provided your target browser suppports [`array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), otherwise use the fallback code on that page.

If you need to remove *all* equal elements, use `filter` as Rocket suggested:

```
removeAll = function(ary, elem) {
    return ary.filter(function(e) { return e != elem });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a modern browser, you can use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(x){
    return this.filter(function(v){
        return v !== x;
    });
};

var a = ["a","b","c"];
var b = a.remove('a');
```

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a simple solution to omit the necessary element from the array:

```
<script>
    function myFunction()
    {
        var fruits = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"];

        <!-- To drop the element "Three"-->
        <!-- splice(elementid, number_of_element_remove) -->
        fruits.splice(2, 1);

        var x = document.getElementById("demo");
        x.innerHTML = fruits;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: this is valid for Array and arraylist both

Answer (score 1):

```
let xx = ['a','a','b','c'];  // Array
let elementToRemove = 'a';  // Element to remove
xx =xx.filter((x) => x != elementToRemove) // xx will contain all elements except 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the additional payload (around 4 kB minified and gzipped) you could use the [without function of the Underscore.js library](http://underscorejs.org/#without):

```
_.without(["a", "b", "c"], "a");
```

[Underscore.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore.js) would give you this function + a lot of very convenient functions.